# What is the running time? is it O(n)?

Tags: scheme, performance

I think the running time of this solution is O(n). But, I'm not sure. Can anyone help me figure it out?

```
(define (poly x coeff)
  (polyaux x (reverse coeff) 0))

;; the aux function
(define (polyaux x coeff acc)
  (if (null? coeff)
      acc
      (polyaux x (cdr coeff) (+ (* acc x) (car coeff)))))
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the n in O(n) refers to the length of coeff, then it has to be. At every step, coeff gets one item shorter until it is gone.